# how to remove pan gesture from label after tapping over label

Tags: ios

i am adding multiple label with pan gesture and tap gesture over each label.But when i tap over any label ,pan gesture is not removing from other label ?

```
- (void)oneTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

     tapedLabel=gesture.view.tag;
     //NSLog(@" tapped label is %d",numberOfLabel);

    //add pangesture
    self.pangesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)] ;
    [self.pangesture  setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [self.pangesture  setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [ self.pangesture  setDelegate:self];

        for(int i=1;i<=numberOfLabel;i++)
        { 
             UILabel *label=[self.labelDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
            label.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
           if(i==tapedLabel)
           {
               //NSLog(@"i value %i tag value %d",i,tapedLabel);

               [label addGestureRecognizer:self.pangesture];
              // NSLog(@"remove  gesture over label %@",label);


           }
            else
            {
                //NSLog(@"i value %i tag value %d",i,tapedLabel);

           [label removeGestureRecognizer:self.pangesture];

               NSLog(@"add gesture over label %@",label);
            }

               }

   }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this to remove your panGesture,

if you have two gestures for a label, use following.

```
if (label.gestureRecognizers.count > 1)
     [label removeGestureRecognizer:[label.gestureRecognizers lastObject]];
```